# Accessing JSON nested data

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to access the values node in the following JSON document using something like this (assume data is the JSON document):

```
console.log(data.values);
```

Is this because the document is one big array?

```
[
  {
     "key": "Failed",
     "vis": "1",
     "values": [
        {
           "date": "2014-02-26T05:00:00.000Z",
           "total": 0.07142857142857142
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "key": "Pass",
     "vis": "1",
     "values": [
        {
           "date": "2014-02-26T05:00:00.000Z",
           "total": 1.325781
        }
     ]
  },
]
```

Comment: Looks like you have defined an array of objects. so you could access values with: `data[INDEX]['values']`, where INDEX is 0 or 1 in the provided example

Comment: If `data` is really a JSON document, you also need to use `JSON.parse` to parse it into a Javascript object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're dealing with a nested array structure, you'd have to do something like below to extract and aggregate the values into a more accessible collection

```
var objects = [
  {
     "key": "Failed",
     "vis": "1",
     "values": [
        {
           "date": "2014-02-26T05:00:00.000Z",
           "total": 0.07142857142857142
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "key": "Pass",
     "vis": "1",
     "values": [
        {
           "date": "2014-02-26T05:00:00.000Z",
           "total": 1.325781
        }
     ]
  },
];

var aggregates = [];

objects.forEach(function(o, i){
   o.values.forEach(function(v, i){
      aggregates.push(v);
   });
});

console.log(aggregates);
```